# Duplicate values pandas

Tags: pandas, pandas-groupby, pandasql, pandas-apply, pandas-profiling

I am new to pandas.
I have been trying to solve a problem here

[This is the problem statement where I want to drop any row where I have a duplicate A but non duplicate B](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qFhZG.png)

Here is the kind of output I want

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M3163.png)

Answer (score 1):

IIUC, this is what you need

```
a = (df['A'].ne(df['A'].shift())).ne((df['B'].ne(df['B'].shift())))
df[~a].reset_index(drop=True)
```

**Output**

```
    A   B
0   2   z
1   3   x
2   3   x
```

Comment: this is not the expected output

Comment: @Krishan, can you clarify? based on your description, my code keeps the first row, however, your picture seems to keep the 2nd row. Can you clarify which is correct?

Answer (score 1):

I think you need:

```
cond=(df.eq(df.shift(-1))|df.eq(df.shift())).all(axis=1)
pd.concat([df[~cond].groupby('A').last().reset_index(),df[cond]])

    A   B
0   2   y
2   3   x
3   3   x
```